# Conditional Filtering using Devel Version of Dplyr's Scoped Filter

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
library(dplyr) devel version, soon-to-be released 0.6
library(tidyr)
```

Below is a simple dataset. The Q1Sat-Q3Sat variables are satisfaction levels, and the Q1Used-Q3Used variables refer to whether the survey respondent used the item that they are rating. The questions are asked together on the survey. In reality, the real dataset contains at least 50 of the Sat variables and Used variables.

```
Q1Sat<-c("Neutral","Neutral","VSat","Sat","Neutral","Sat","VDis","Sat","Sat","VSat")
Q2Sat<-c("Neutral","VSat","Dis","Dis","VDis","Sat","Sat","VSat","Neutral","Dis")
Q3Sat<-c("Sat","Sat","Diss","Neutral","VSat","VDis","Sat","Sat","Sat","Neutral")
Q3Used<-c("Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No")
Q2Used<-c("Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes")
Q1Used<-c("Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","Yes")
House<-c("Yes","No","Unsure","Yes","Yes","No","Unsure","Unsure","Yes","Yes")

Test<-data_frame(Q1Sat,Q2Sat,Q3Sat,Q1Used,Q2Used,Q3Used,House)
```

I want to restructure the data using the code below into a table with percentages. However, I need to filter q1Used - q3Used variables to only include "Yes", and the House variable to only include "Yes". As already mentioned, q1Sat is tied to q1Used, so q1Sat should only be included if q1Used is "Yes, and the House variable is "Yes". I need to do this for q2Sat and q3Sat.

However, I'm stuck on how to accomplish this. I tried using the scoped filter from the devel version of dplyr, but I'm not sure how to use it with multiple variables - q1Used:q3Used, as well as House

So how would I add the filter for House != "Yes" to the scoped filter in the code below?

```
Test%>%
filter_at(vars(Q1Used:Q35Used),all_vars(. != 1)%>%
select(Q1Sat:Q3Sat)%>%
gather()%>%
count(key,value)%>%
mutate(perc=round(n/sum(n),2))%>%
select(-n)%>%
spread(value,perc)
```

Comment: If you have selected only 'Sat' variables, how you are getting th 'Used' variables for `filter`?  Also, based on your condition (`q1Used - q3Used variables to only include "Yes", and the House variable to only include "No"`), after the filtering there will be 0 rows because none of the rows are meeting the condition

Comment: I guess I should include the "Used" variables in the select then...that's part of the issue as well, I'm just hoping to find an easier way to write the code above using pipes and tidyverse. As for none of the rows meeting the condition, I changed the "House" variable from no to yes. It really doesn't matter, it's more to learn how to use the scoped filter on different types of variables together...

Comment: I edited the code...it should be better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without devel version. General idea is that we recode undesired values to NA instead of filtering.

```
sat = Test %>% select(Q1Sat:Q3Sat, House) %>%
      gather(key_sat, Sat, -House)
used = Test %>% select(Q1Used:Q3Used) %>%
    gather(key_used, Used)

cbind(used, sat) %>% 
    group_by(key_sat) %>% 
    mutate(
        value = ((Used != "No") & (House == "Yes")) * 1,
        base = sum(value)
    ) %>% 
    group_by(key_sat, Sat) %>% 
    summarise(perc = sum(value)/sum(base[1])) %>% 
    spread(Sat,perc)
```